# Know when a mapped network drive has been connected and disconnected

Tags: network-shares, windows-server-2008-r2

Scenario: A NAS which sometimes has its LAN cable unplug and plugged back again. Is there a way to know exactly when a mapped network drive has been phisicaly connected and disconnected? Like an entry in Windows Event Viewer.

Comment: If You have direct cable link You will see `Link down/up` in event log. If not... I think no reliable solution without additional software exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1323173/pinging-is-not-recognized-as-an-external-or-internal-command#comment1972516_1323173) question was asked for a command line. This command line displays output of `PING` command with time stamp.

`ping -t 8.8.8.8|cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!time! !data!)&ping -n 2 8.8.8.8>nul"`

This command can be used to get information you need. It will show a timeout, when network cable is unplugged. You just need to change the command with `IP` of your server.

Comment: I did not implement this one, but it actually gave an idea to just log ping within a certain time interval with current date/time to a txt file. Thanks! :D

Comment: @AbianG if that means you no longer need help, please accept this answer, so others know you no longer need help, even if it technically was not the answer you used.

Comment: I ended up using another script but you are right. Marked as answer :)